# Docker - Explain used space by images and containers

Tags: debian, docker

I'm using `Docker` and try to understand how used space is managed. When I run `docker system df`, I can see the size of my images and containers. I previously run a `docker system prune` to clear every unsued elements, so it's very reasonable and it looks like I'm using around 5GB

[image: docker_system_df]

When I'm analyzing used/avalaible space with `df -h` on the entire system I find others informations and don't understand why I have 86GB of used space

[image: df_h]

A quicklook in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` reveal a large amount of files, maybe there are still old unused elements ?

[image: overlay2]

How to explain this difference and what are those 86GB of used space ? I thought `docker system df` clear every unsed elements like images, volumes, cache so how to explain those amount of used space ?

Comment: I believe that "86 GB" is also used by whatever is using your root partition. Note the "overlay" partition type as well as the fact that the stats for `/` mirrors that of `/var/lib/docker` exactly.

Comment: Ok, this display confused me. You suggests there are "double counts" ?

Comment: I suggest you look up overlay mounts and OverlayFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As docker storage is inside `/` as `/var/lib/docker`, `docker system df` shows only the size of images/containers. If you want to reclaim space the command is `docker system prune` but in your case it seems there is nothing to reclaim. You can set your docker storage anywhere tweaking the service and adding `--data-root=/data/docker/data` style storage.

Comment: What is the content of `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/` ? I don't understand why there is 158 files.

Comment: in overlay2 itsn't files but directories that are merged to create a complete OS which depends of your Dockerfile.